# Swagger annotation error 500 in php laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, swagger, swagger-php

```
 *     @SWG\Get(
 *      path="/settings",
 *      tags={"Settings"},
 *      operationId="settingsindex",
 *      summary="Get settings.",
 *      @SWG\Response(
 *          response=200,
 *          description="success",
 *          @SWG\Schema(ref="common/Settings/Settings"),
 *      ),
 *      @SWG\Response(
 *          response="default",
 *          description="error",
 *          @SWG\Schema(ref="app/Error"),
 *      ),
 *  )
 *
 *
```

I'm writing swagger annotation in PHP laravel 5 using swagger version 1.0.0. I got 500 response code. I'm giving the correct module reference but get 500, 403 and 405 response code. Can anyone figure out what is my mistake?

Comment: Where exactly are you getting/seeing the 500 code?

Comment: On swagger UI where my api's are rendering when I click on try out then I see 500 response code and some returns 405 and 403.

Comment: validator.swagger.io didn't return any error.

Comment: Errors returned from "try it out" are actual responses from your API. Check your controller code to see why they might return 500/405/403.